# Why max_batches independent of the size of the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, yolo, darknet

I am wondering why the number of images has no influence on the number of iterations when training. Here is an example to to make my question clearer:
Suppose we have 6400 images for a training to recognize 4 classes. Based on AlexeyAB explanations, we keep batch= 64, subdivisions = 16 and write max_batches = 8000 since max_batches is determined by #classes x 2000.

Since we have 6400 images, a complete epoch requires 100 iterations. Therefore this training ends after 80 epochs.
Now, suppose that we have 12800 images. In that case, an epoch needs 200 iterations. Therefore the training ends after 40 epochs.
Since an epoch refers to one cycle through the full training dataset, I'm wondering why we don't increase the number of iterations when our dataset increases, in order to keep the number of epochs constant.

Said differently, I'm asking for a simple explanation as to why the number of epochs seems to be irrelevant to the quality of the training. I feel that it's a consequence of Yolo's construction but I am not knowledgeable enough to understand how.

Answer (score 2):

Why the number of images has no influence on the number of iterations when training?

- In darknet yolo, the number of iterations depends on the `max_batches` parameter in `.cfg` file. After running for `max_batches`, the darknet saves the `final_weights`.

In each epoch, all the data samples are passed through the network, so if you have many images, the training time for one epoch (and iteration) will be higher, you can test that by increasing images in your data.

The sub-division accounts for the number of mini-batches. Let's say, you have 100 images in your dataset. your batch size is 10, sub-division is 2, max_batches is 20.

So, in each iteration, 10 images are passed to the network in two mini-batches (Each having 5 samples), once you have done 20 baches (20*10 data samples), the training will be completed. (The details can be a little different, I'm using a slightly modified darknet by original author `pjreddie`)

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are updated now. `max_batches` is equal to `classes*2000` but not less than **number of training images** and not less than 6000. Please find it at this [link](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects).